# Function notation: meaning of notation $f_k(x)$

Tags: functions, plane-curves

I found this in a 2013 MAT question whilst practising past papers and am not sure of the meaning of this notation. Keep  in mind my understanding of maths is only at the level of Scottish Highers (similar to A level maths).

question iii) asks about $f_k(x)$ and $f_{2-k}(x)$, what is the difference?

The answers to question i) also reference a polynomial $p_3$ where 3 is the highest index of the polynomial, is this also what is meant by the notation for $f_k(x)$?

The question for context

[image]

Comment: $f_k$ is a function depending on a fixed parameter $k$. It means that $f_1(x)=x\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)$ and $f_{1,5}\left(x\right)=x\left(x-1,5\right)\left(x-2\right)$ for example. You can see it as a "family" of functions.

Comment: The meaning of $f_k$ is given at the top-right corner of the image. (BTW, Questions here are preferably kept self-contained, i.e., not requiring readers to leave the webpage.) I imagine $f_{2-k}$ jus means to replace every occurrence of $k$ in that function expression with $2-k.$

Comment: The link says it. $f_k(x)=x(x-k)(x-2)$  You get a function for every value of $k$.  $f_7(x)=x(x-7)(x-2)$ for example.  This has nothing to do with $p_3$.

Answer (score 0):

$f_k$ is just used to denote a family of functions. It's just like you define a sequence $a_k=2k-1$, which gives all odd numbers. You put a value of $k$, say $7$ and get back the value of $a_7$. Here, $k$ is just a parameter. In your case for example, you will have
$$f_7(x)=x(x-7)(x-2)$$
$$f_{2-k}(x)=x\Big(x-(2-k)\Big)(x-7)=x(x+k-2)(x-7)$$
Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)